# Postgres: Link sequence date virtual table to real table

Tags: postgresql, date, sequence

Newbie here in PostgreSQL.

I have some SQL which basically lists a sequence of dates from `2/4/2013` to `10/7/2013`.
For example:

```
select date(generate_series(DATE '20130402', DATE '20131007', interval '1' day))
```

**Output:**

```
"2013-04-02"
"2013-04-03"
"2013-04-04"
"2013-04-05"
"2013-04-06"
```

Then I have another SQL from `myorder` table:

```
select date(date_created) as date_created1, count(id) from myorder group by date_created1 order by date_created1 desc
```

**Output:**

```
"2013-08-12;2"
"2013-08-08";1"
"2013-08-02";1"
"2013-08-01";1"
```

Basically, this shows the total orders per day.

My question is how do I link the first SQL to the 2nd one, so that it will output date and count sequentially (ordered by date). Also, if no order is found in the "myorder" table, it will show "0" instead.

For Example:

`2013-08-11` does not have any order record, so the count column will show `"0"`.

More less like this:

```
"2013-08-12;2"
"2013-08-11;0"
"2013-08-10;0"
"2013-08-09;0"
"2013-08-08;1"
"2013-08-02;1"
"2013-08-01;1"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just join both, as the following:

```
SELECT dt.d AS date_created1, count(m.id)
FROM
    (
    SELECT date(d)
        FROM generate_series(
            DATE '20130402', DATE '20131007', interval '1' day
        ) AS d
    ) AS dt
    LEFT JOIN myorder m ON m.date_created = dt.d
GROUP BY date_created1
ORDER BY date_created1 DESC
```

You could also use min/max to get the first and last date values.

Comment: Tried that, got this error: ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Comment: Figured out, by take "date" out of "generate_series", it solves the issue. The complete SQL would be: 

SELECT date(dt.d) AS date_created1, count(m.id)
FROM generate_series(DATE '20130402', DATE '20131007', interval '1' day) AS dt(d)
     LEFT JOIN myorder m ON date(m.date_created) = date(dt.d)
GROUP BY date_created1
ORDER BY date_created1 DESC

Thank you @MatheusOl for the idea.

Comment: @user2856772, you are right... I corrected to make it right, and used a different approach from yours (which I think it is clearer)... check that.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a CTE makes things a bit easier to read - but that is of course personal choice:

```
with all_dates as (
  select d::date as 
  from generate_series(DATE '2013-04-02', DATE '2013-10-07', interval '1' day) d
) 
select ad.d,
       count(mo.id) as order_count
from all_dates ad
  left join myorder mo on mo.date_created = ad.d
group by ad.d
order by ad.d;
```